# Rotating an image java GUI

Tags: java, user-interface

I want to rotate a image around this oval track:

[image]

This is my code:

```
if(xloc >= 637 && yloc >= 275) //bottom-right quadrant image rotation statement
        {
            angle = Math.atan((double)(yloc-275)/(900-xloc));
            //radians = Math.toRadians(angle);
            //radians += Math.PI;
            radians = Math.round(radians*10000000.0)/10000000.0;
        }
        else if(xloc >= 637 && yloc <= 275) //top-right quadrant image rotation statement
        {
            angle = Math.PI - Math.atan(yloc/(900-xloc));
            //radians = Math.toRadians(angle);
            radians = Math.round(radians*10000000.0)/10000000.0;
        }
        else if(xloc <= 263 && yloc <= 275) //top-left quadrant image rotation statement
        {
            angle = Math.PI + Math.atan(yloc/xloc);
            //radians = Math.toRadians(angle);
            radians = Math.round(radians*10000000.0)/10000000.0;
        }
        else if(xloc <= 264 && yloc >= 275) //bottom-left quadrant image rotation statement
        {
            angle = (2*Math.PI) - Math.atan((yloc-275)/xloc);
            //radians = Math.toRadians(angle);
            radians = Math.round(radians*10000000.0)/10000000.0;
        }
//casting the graphics object to Graphics2D
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
        //AffineTransform object image rotation
        AffineTransform a = AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(radians,xloc,yloc);
        //moving the image at x and y locations
        a.translate(xloc,yloc);
        //drawing the user's horse chariot image and applying all transformations to the image when it is drawn
        g2d.drawImage(horse,a,null);
```

Why isn't the image being rotated? What should I change so that it will?

Comment: Check out this similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8639567/java-rotating-images

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java: Rotating Images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8639567/java-rotating-images)

Comment: I'm thinking you probably want something more [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32392095/how-to-rotate-a-rectangle-after-reaching-specified-position/32397121#32397121)