# How can I find all of the coordinates along an Arc2D in Java?

Tags: java, graphics, coordinates, graphics2d

I have drawn an Arc2D in Java and I want to be able to find all of the points that the Arc2D contains. Is there any way that I can do that?

Comment: You need to use a `PathIterator`, for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32392095/how-to-rotate-a-rectangle-after-reaching-specified-position/32397121#32397121). Remember, a Circle is just made of a lot of straight lines, depending on the "flatness" (or the number of points used to make the shape)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to make use of a [`PathIterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/geom/PathIterator.html)

Basically this will allow you to iterator between the points that make up the path.  You can control the "accuracy" (or distance between the points) using the `flatness` parameter

For example...

[image][image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.geom.Arc2D;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.geom.PathIterator;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSlider;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

public final class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private Arc2D shape;
        private double flatness = 0.4;

        public TestPane() {
            shape = new Arc2D.Double(50, 50, 100, 100, 0, 180, Arc2D.OPEN);

            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            JSlider slider = new JSlider(0, 100);
            slider.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                    double progress = slider.getValue() / 100d;
                    flatness = 0.001 + (0.4d * progress);
                    repaint();
                }
            });
            slider.setValue(0);

            add(slider, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.draw(shape);
            g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
            PathIterator pi = shape.getPathIterator(null, flatness);
            // Use this if you want to draw lines between the points
            Point2D lastPoint;
            while (!pi.isDone()) {
                double[] coords = new double[6];
                switch (pi.currentSegment(coords)) {
                    case PathIterator.SEG_MOVETO:
                        // Starting point of next line
                        lastPoint = new Point2D.Double(coords[0], coords[1]);
                        // You don't need this if you're drawing lines
                        g2d.fill(new Ellipse2D.Double(coords[0] - 2, coords[1] - 2, 4, 4));
                        break;
                    case PathIterator.SEG_LINETO:
                        g2d.fill(new Ellipse2D.Double(coords[0] - 2, coords[1] - 2, 4, 4));
                        // If you were drawing lines, then you'd draw a line
                        // between the last point and this point
                        lastPoint = new Point2D.Double(coords[0], coords[1]);
                        break;
                }
                pi.next();
            }
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }
}
```